# .htaccess is not working in Ubuntu Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

Actually I have activated mode_rewrite in Apache.

```
core mod_so mod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version 
mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core 
mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex 
mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_filter mod_mime prefork mod_negotiation 
mod_php5 **mod_rewrite** mod_setenvif mod_status
```

But .htaccess file is not working.

Comment: How do yu determine that it's "not working"?

Answer (score -1):

Same problem was with me.
There are mainly two reason for that.

1. Misconfiguration of apache.
2. php version.

I recommend you to first update your php in ubuntu.

Comment: .htaccess is an Apache config file, it has nothing to do with PHP. "Misconfiguration of apache" - could you be anymore vague?